# Doing multiple calculation when we `groupby` in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As I learned so far, each time we do `groupby` on a dataframe in pandas we could do only one calculation, e.g. mean of columns.

How could we do multiple calculations (as we could do in SQL) in only one `groupby` in pandas.

For example for dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
times = [21 , 34, 37, 40, 55, 65, 67, 84, 88, 90 , 91, 97, 104,105, 108]
names = ['bob', 'alice', 'bob', 'bob' , 'ali', 'alice', 'alice' , 'ali', 'moji', 'ali', 'moji', 'alice' , 'bob', 'bob', 'bob']
user_answer = [2 , 2 , 1 , 3 , 1 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 ,1 , 4]
correct_answer = [2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 3 ,1 , 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : names , 'time' : times , 'user_answer'  : user_answer ,  'correct_answer'  : correct_answer})
```

how could I get a dataframe with three columns:

name: Each name repeated only one time (by doing `groupby` names)

mean_time: `mean` of times next to that name

score: How many time `user_answer` is equals to `correct_answer` for that user

**With only one `groupby` code?**

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper column with compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregations:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df.user_answer.eq(df.correct_answer))
         .groupby('name').agg(mean_time = ('time','mean'),
                             score=('new','sum'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
    name  mean_time  score
0    ali  76.333333      3
1  alice  65.750000      1
2    bob  69.166667      5
3   moji  89.500000      1
```

Comment: Very excellent! What if I want more complicated calculation say want another column in which we have `time_to_get_one_score` i.e. `mean_time`/`score` for each name? I should write a new code or it could be in the same code? @jezrael

Comment: @moshtaba - I think then best shoul dbe add new colum nafter my solution with divide like `df1['new'] = df1['mean_time'].div(df1['score'])`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def f(gdf):
  res = pd.Series()
  res['mean_time'] = gdf['times'].mean()
  res['score'] = len(gdf[gdf['user_answer']==gdf['correct_answer']])
  return res

df.groupby(['names']).apply(f)
```